# Converting plural words to singular in Python

Tags: python, string

I have an Excel file with word count as below:

```
1.Chip, 5
2.Chips,8
3.Car, 2
4.Cars, 6
```

I want to make output as:

```
Chip 13
Car 8
```

Comment: What about singular words which ends in `s`, such as `scissors`?  To handle this problem in general, you would need to refer to a dictionary first, then lop off the final `s` for words which really are in plural form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [inflect](https://github.com/jaraco/inflect) package with a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import inflect

p = inflect.engine()
l = {"chip": 5, "chips": 8, "car": 2, "cars": 6}
updated = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in l.items():
    singular_key = p.singular_noun(k) or k  # make singular if needed
    updated[singular_key] += v

print(dict(updated))
```

Which gives the output:

```
{'chip': 13, 'car': 8}
```